# XCUITest Error: Left Mouse Down: Failed to find matching element - Xcode error

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, xcode-ui-testing, nsbutton

I'm in the process of constructing a UI test for my macOS application. This is using Xcode 8 on macOS Sierra. One thing that I noticed is as I record my UI test, I receive a strange error when clicking on my custom control `NSButton` subclass. The error message is: `Recorder Service Error: Left Mouse Down: Failed to find matching element - Xcode error`

Upon googling this error it seems that this is an issue related to accessibility or a bug in AppKit or some combination of the two. I did try the same approach again using an `NSView` custom control subclass (using a `mouseDown:` override to simulate a button click) the UI test was able to find and successfully record this event in the test. However, there seems to be a very specific problem when doing this with `NSButton`.

**Other things I tried:**

In the identity inspector I did set the Identifier property to a specific value, but this also seemed to have no beneficial effect upon recording my UI test.

I also tried overriding:

```
  override func accessibilityPerformPress() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

But this also seems to have no noticeable effect as `NSButton` already conforms to `NSAccessibilityButton`.

I also tried throwing a breakpoint in the UITest and printing the entire XCUIApplication tree via `po XCUIApplication()` in the Xcode console and I did notice that my custom control does not seem to appear in the tree hierarchy.

Here is a snapshot as to what my storyboard looks like in my little sample application:

[image]

I've included both a system push button (which can be found and properly recorded) as well as my custom control NSButton below it.

Also here is a snapshot of the XCUIApplication tree in the console:

[image]

The code for my NSButton subclass looks like this:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomButton : NSButton {

    //MARK: - Properties

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : Float = 0
    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor : NSColor = NSColor.clear
    @IBInspectable var buttonText : String?
    @IBInspectable var textColor : NSColor = NSColor.white
    @IBInspectable var selectedTextColor : NSColor = NSColor.white
    @IBInspectable var borderColor : NSColor = NSColor.clear
    @IBInspectable var fontSize : Int = 13
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : Float = 1.5
    @IBInspectable var shouldBoldText : Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var shouldUnderlineText : Bool = false

    fileprivate var isSetup = false
    fileprivate var isSelected = false

    internal var buttonTextField : NSTextField?

    //MARK: - Inteface Builder Managemenet

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        configureView()
    }


    override func accessibilityPerformPress() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    //MARK: - Init

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureView()
    }

    //MARK: - View Configuration and Styling


    /// Configures the control UI elements and all styling options.
    internal func configureView() {
        if isSetup == false {
            setAccessibilityElement(true)
            isSetup = true
            configureButtonTextField()
            styleView()
        }
    }

    /// Configures the button text field and applies auto layout.
    fileprivate func configureButtonTextField() {

        buttonTextField = NSTextField(frame: bounds)
        buttonTextField!.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        buttonTextField!.isBordered = false
        buttonTextField!.isEditable = false
        buttonTextField!.isSelectable = false
        buttonTextField!.isBezeled = false
        buttonTextField!.drawsBackground = false
        buttonTextField!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(buttonTextField!)

        //Apply the auto layout.

        let horizontalXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonTextField!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let verticalYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonTextField!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        addConstraint(horizontalXConstraint)
        addConstraint(verticalYConstraint)
    }

    /// Applies all the user defined runtime attributes. attriutes all have
    /// fallback values in case none were set in interface builder.
    fileprivate func styleView() {

        wantsLayer = true

        layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
        layer?.cornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRadius)
        layer?.masksToBounds = true

        if let buttonText = buttonText {
            buttonTextField?.stringValue = buttonText
        }

        buttonTextField?.textColor = textColor
        buttonTextField?.textColor = selectedTextColor
        layer?.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor

        layer?.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)

        if shouldBoldText == true {
            buttonTextField?.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontSize))
        } else {
            buttonTextField?.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontSize))
        }
    }


    /// Updates the text color for the button text field. Updatse the selected
    /// text color to match the defined color.
    ///
    /// - parameter textColor: The color to change the button textfield text to.
    internal func styleButtonText(textColor : NSColor) {
        self.textColor = textColor
        buttonTextField?.textColor = textColor
        selectedTextColor = textColor
    }

    //MARK: - Click Management

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {


        isSelected = true
        alphaValue = 0.7
        buttonTextField?.textColor = selectedTextColor

    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {

        alphaValue = 1.0
        buttonTextField?.textColor = textColor
        isSelected = false

        guard let target = target, let action = action else {
            return
        }

        NSApp.sendAction(action, to: target, from: self)

    }

    //MARK: - Cursor Rect Management

    override func resetCursorRects() {
        addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: NSCursor.pointingHand())
    }
}
```

I'm pretty stumped on this one. System controls seem to record and work just fine in UITesting but custom controls, at least of NSButton, seem to cause problems. If anyone has any ideas on what may be causing this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure that your button's isAccessibilityElement attribute is set to yes?

Comment: I updated the post by adding in  setAccessibilityElement(true) in the configureView method. I still have the same problem after setting this property to true.

Comment: Is the text field the same size as the button?

Comment: Yeah the frame of the textField is set to the bounds of the NSButton and positioned in the center.

Comment: So the button is unclickable.

Comment: No the button is clickable, the click method will still be called for the IBAction. Even commenting out all the subview controls, the problem still occurs.

Comment: I tried this. My textfield is very small. Recording a test and clicking on the button works, clicking on the textfield doesn't.

Comment: This is really strange behavior. Even commenting out my textfield subview and just recording the button by itself, I still receive the same error message that i posted in the question. Very inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @Willeke If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it. There were two problems going on and your suggestion solved part of it. The other half was the UI Element I had on my XIB was a 'Custom View', it needs to be any type of NSButton for this to work properly.